# Nuget Package restore Added Package is not restored

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

I am trying to install NuGet Packages with command line, because in Visual studio I get errors, that Visual Studio can't access some nuget Dlls because a proccess is accessing them.

So I've used this command line to install the Packagages from my sln

```
nuget.exe reinstall -Force c:\GIT\Sales.Bazar\Sales.Bazar.sln
```

that runns without any problem, but Not all of my NuGet packages are getting installed.

in the commandline Output I can see for example

```
Restoring NuGet package Ninject.3.2.2.
Adding package 'Ninject.3.2.2' to folder 'c:\GIT\Sales.Bazar\packages'
```

But when I take a look in my packages folder, there is no such package stored

[image]

I dont know what I am missing that the packages are not showing up

Answer (score 0):

when I am changing my nuget command line to this and adding the **-NoCache** option

```
nuget.exe reinstall -Force -NoCache c:\GIT\Sales.Bazar\Sales.Bazar.sln
```

all packages are getting downloaded into my Package folder.